# OneGraph and Graphql Codegen outputs enums with numeric values

Tags: typescript, enums, graphql, next.js, code-generation

So I just migrated my entire codebase for a project from using the direct Headless Wordpress GraphQL endpoint to using OneGraph for Google+Facebook Business support. OneGraph is an amazing tool, intend to use it in a tech ed course I'm writing on headless WordPress actually. Anyway, I am getting this apollo error, it is referencing the output codegen. Here's the error:

```
  graphQLErrors: [
    {
      message: 'Variable "$idTypeFoot" got invalid value 2; Expected type MenuNodeIdTypeEnum.',
      path: [Array],
      extensions: [Object]
    },
    {
      message: 'Variable "$idTypeFoot" got invalid value 2; Expected type MenuNodeIdTypeEnum.',
      path: [Array],
      extensions: [Object]
    }
  ],
```

Here's the output codegen definition in my generated/graphql.tsx file:

```
export enum WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum {
    /** Identify a menu node by the Database ID. */
    DATABASE_ID = 0,
    /** Identify a menu node by the (hashed) Global ID. */
    ID = 1,
    /** Identify a menu node by it's name */
    NAME = 2
}
```

Here is the previous definition of that same enum prior to migrating my codebase to onegraph:

```
/** The Type of Identifier used to fetch a single node. Default is "ID". To be used along with the "id" field. */
export enum MenuNodeIdTypeEnum {
    /** Identify a menu node by the Database ID. */
    DatabaseId = 'DATABASE_ID',
    /** Identify a menu node by the (hashed) Global ID. */
    Id = 'ID',
    /** Identify a menu node by it's name */
    Name = 'NAME'
}
```

Here is the `dynamic-nav-fields.graphql` partial used in the parent query:

```
fragment DynamicNavFragment on WordpressMenuItem {
    id
    label
    path
    parentId
}
```

Here is the `dynamic-nav.graphql` parent query:

```
# import DynamicNavFragment from './Partials/dynamic-nav-fields.graphql'

query DynamicNav(
  $idHead: ID!
  $idTypeHead: WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum!
  $idFoot: ID!
  $idTypeFoot: WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum!
    ) {
    Header: wordpress {
        menu(id: $idHead, idType: $idTypeHead) {
            menuItems(where: { parentId: 0 }) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        ...DynamicNavFragment
                        childItems {
                            edges {
                                node {
                                    ...DynamicNavFragment
                                    childItems {
                                        edges {
                                            node {
                                                ...DynamicNavFragment
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Footer: wordpress {
        menu(id: $idFoot, idType: idTypeFoot) {
            menuItems(where: { parentId: 0 }) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        ...DynamicNavFragment
                        childItems {
                            edges {
                                node {
                                    ...DynamicNavFragment
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my codegen.yml configuration file:

```yaml
overwrite: true
schema:
  ${WORDPRESS_API_URL_YML}:
    headers:
      Authorization: Bearer ${WORDPRESS_AUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN_YML}
documents: 'graphql/**/*.graphql'
generates:
  graphql/generated/graphql.tsx:
    plugins:
      - typescript:
          constEnums: false
          enumsAsTypes: false          
          numericEnums: true
          futureProofEnums: false
          enumsAsConst: false
          onlyOperationTypes: false
          maybeValue: T | null | undefined
          noExport: false
          enumPrefix: true
          fieldWrapperValue: T
          wrapFieldDefinitions: true
          skipTypename: false
          nonOptionalTypename: false
          useTypeImports: false
          avoidOptionals: true
          declarationKind: 
            input: interface
            type: interface
      - typescript-operations:
          declarationKind:
            input: interface
            type: interface
          avoidOptionals: true
          exportFragmentSpreadSubTypes: true
      - typescript-react-apollo:
          addDocBlocks: true
          reactApolloVersion: 3
          documentMode: documentNodeImportFragments
    config:
      maybeValue: T | null | undefined
      declarationKind:
        input: interface
        type: interface
      documentNodeImportFragments: true
      reactApolloVersion: 3
      withHooks: true
      withHOC: false
      avoidOptionals: true
      withComponent: false
      exportFragmentSpreadSubTypes: true
      addDocBlocks: true
  graphql/graphql.schema.graphql:
    plugins:
      - schema-ast
    config:
      commentDescriptions: true
  graphql/graphql.schema.json:
    plugins:
      - introspection
    config:
      commentDescriptions: true
      
hooks:
  afterAllFileWrite: 
    - prettier --write
```

Why is OneGraph replacing the generated Enum values with numbers that apollo client can't read? If anyone knows how to resolve this please let me know

Comment: `numericEnums: true` ?

Comment: it was throwing an error prior to that because onegraph was outputing numeric enums regardless of the flag. I had it set to false initially and the only difference was wrapping 2 as "2"

Comment: just use WP types generated separately? https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/ ... you can customize enums https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-resolvers#enum-resolvers

Comment: That’s what I mention in my answer below, thanks though

Comment: a few steps [with manual work] later ...  you can setup own federated API ;)

Comment: Is the schema available to test somewhere? I'd love to look at where the numeric enums are coming from!

Comment: absolutely, if you message me on linkedin I'd be happy to shoot over both the WordPress and OneGraph endpoints/environmental variables! or for the full zip + endpoints/enviornmental vars join my slack workspace 
LinkedIn - https://www.linkedin.com/in/asross/
Slack - https://join.slack.com/t/freelancedeve-hcr2145/shared_invite/zt-emhcj1mb-hS_5wUHoyA~nV5vZdyVa4A

Comment: @AndrewRoss joined, too ... but IDK OneGraph at all ... probably based on Apollo Federation with some optimizations/integrations/auth solution/etc. ... https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/value-types/ ... didn't used this, either .... I can help with WPGQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr; change `codegen.yml` to use `numericEnums: false`:

```yaml
generates:
  graphql/generated/graphql.tsx:
    plugins:
      - typescript:
          numericEnums: false
```

To track this down, I took the GraphQL SDL definition of `WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum`:

```
enum WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum {
    # Identify a menu node by the Database ID.
    DATABASE_ID
    # Identify a menu node by the (hashed) Global ID.
    ID
    # Identify a menu node by it's name
    NAME
}
```

along with the previous `numericEnums: true` setting in `codegen.yml`, and used them on the playground at https://www.graphql-code-generator.com
[image: numericEnums: true]

As you can see in the screenshot, the SDL definition was compiled into numeric enums (the standard for typescript enums at runtime)

I then tested with `numericEnums: false`:
[image: numericEnums: false]

And that output looks like what you'd expect, where `WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum.Name` is equal to `"NAME"`, so that Apollo gets the expected value instead of the runtime typescript-enum value (`2`).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE — see @sgrove’s answer, he was awesome and helped me troubleshoot the issue!

okay, there were two options I had: (1) overwrite each enum converted from a string value representative of the __type previously *or* (2) hardcode these values in. To get the custom enum value I had to add the following to my codegen.yml:

```yaml
config:
    enumValues:
       WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum: '@/types/global-enums#WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum'
```

which directs the generated code to import this enum definition from @/types/global-enums.ts

```
/** The Type of Identifier used to fetch a single node. Default is "ID". To be used along with the "id" field. */
export enum WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum {
    /** Identify a menu node by the Database ID. */
    DatabaseId = 'DATABASE_ID',
    /** Identify a menu node by the (hashed) Global ID. */
    Id = 'ID',
    /** Identify a menu node by it's name */
    Name = 'NAME'
}
```

However, I then ran into another issue, and decided to hardcode the `NAME` value in for WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum in my graphql schema directly:

```
# import DynamicNavFragment from './Partials/dynamic-nav-fields.graphql'

query DynamicNav($idHead: ID!, $idFoot: ID!) {
    Header: wordpress {
        menu(id: $idHead, idType: NAME) {
            menuItems(where: { parentId: 0 }) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        ...DynamicNavFragment
                        childItems {
                            edges {
                                node {
                                    ...DynamicNavFragment
                                    childItems {
                                        edges {
                                            node {
                                                ...DynamicNavFragment
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Footer: wordpress {
        menu(id: $idFoot, idType: NAME) {
            menuItems(where: { parentId: 0 }) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        ...DynamicNavFragment
                        childItems {
                            edges {
                                node {
                                    ...DynamicNavFragment
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I ran into an additional issue with the apollo cache since both a top-level ServicesTopQuery and DynamicNavQuery have a shared top level `wordpress` field with a corresponding __typename "WordPressRootQuery".

Codegen definition for `ServicesTopQuery` and `ServicesTopQueryVariables`:

```
export type ServicesTopQueryVariables = Exact<{
    popular: Scalars['String'];
    other: Scalars['String'];
}>;

export type ServicesTopQuery = { __typename?: 'Query' } & {
    popular: Maybe<
        { __typename?: 'WordpressRootQuery' } & {
            services: Maybe<
                { __typename?: 'WordpressRootQueryToServiceConnection' } & {
                    edges: Maybe<
                        Array<
                            Maybe<
                                {
                                    __typename?: 'WordpressRootQueryToServiceConnectionEdge';
                                } & {
                                    node: Maybe<
                                        {
                                            __typename?: 'WordpressService';
                                        } & ServiceFieldsTopFragment
                                    >;
                                }
                            >
                        >
                    >;
                }
            >;
        }
    >;
    other: Maybe<
        { __typename?: 'WordpressRootQuery' } & {
            services: Maybe<
                { __typename?: 'WordpressRootQueryToServiceConnection' } & {
                    edges: Maybe<
                        Array<
                            Maybe<
                                {
                                    __typename?: 'WordpressRootQueryToServiceConnectionEdge';
                                } & {
                                    node: Maybe<
                                        {
                                            __typename?: 'WordpressService';
                                        } & ServiceFieldsTopFragment
                                    >;
                                }
                            >
                        >
                    >;
                }
            >;
        }
    >;
};
```

Codegen definition for `DynamicNavQuery` and `DynamicNavQueryVariables`:

```
export type DynamicNavQueryVariables = Exact<{
    idHead: Scalars['ID'];
    idFoot: Scalars['ID'];
}>;

export type DynamicNavQuery = { __typename?: 'Query' } & {
    Header: Maybe<
        { __typename?: 'WordpressRootQuery' } & {
            menu: Maybe<
                { __typename?: 'WordpressMenu' } & {
                    menuItems: Maybe<
                        { __typename?: 'WordpressMenuToMenuItemConnection' } & {
                            edges: Maybe<
                                Array<
                                    Maybe<
                                        {
                                            __typename?: 'WordpressMenuToMenuItemConnectionEdge';
                                        } & {
                                            node: Maybe<
                                                { __typename?: 'WordpressMenuItem' } & {
                                                    childItems: Maybe<
                                                        {
                                                            __typename?: 'WordpressMenuItemToMenuItemConnection';
                                                        } & {
                                                            edges: Maybe<
                                                                Array<
                                                                    Maybe<
                                                                        {
                                                                            __typename?: 'WordpressMenuItemToMenuItemConnectionEdge';
                                                                        } & {
                                                                            node: Maybe<
                                                                                { __typename?: 'WordpressMenuItem' } & {
                                                                                    childItems: Maybe<
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            __typename?: 'WordpressMenuItemToMenuItemConnection';
                                                                                        } & {
                                                                                            edges: Maybe<
                                                                                                Array<
                                                                                                    Maybe<
                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                            __typename?: 'WordpressMenuItemToMenuItemConnectionEdge';
                                                                                                        } & {
                                                                                                            node: Maybe<
                                                                                                                {
                                                                                                                    __typename?: 'WordpressMenuItem';
                                                                                                                } & DynamicNavFragmentFragment
                                                                                                            >;
                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                    >
                                                                                                >
                                                                                            >;
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    >;
                                                                                } & DynamicNavFragmentFragment
                                                                            >;
                                                                        }
                                                                    >
                                                                >
                                                            >;
                                                        }
                                                    >;
                                                } & DynamicNavFragmentFragment
                                            >;
                                        }
                                    >
                                >
                            >;
                        }
                    >;
                }
            >;
        }
    >;
    Footer: Maybe<
        { __typename?: 'WordpressRootQuery' } & {
            menu: Maybe<
                { __typename?: 'WordpressMenu' } & {
                    menuItems: Maybe<
                        { __typename?: 'WordpressMenuToMenuItemConnection' } & {
                            edges: Maybe<
                                Array<
                                    Maybe<
                                        {
                                            __typename?: 'WordpressMenuToMenuItemConnectionEdge';
                                        } & {
                                            node: Maybe<
                                                { __typename?: 'WordpressMenuItem' } & {
                                                    childItems: Maybe<
                                                        {
                                                            __typename?: 'WordpressMenuItemToMenuItemConnection';
                                                        } & {
                                                            edges: Maybe<
                                                                Array<
                                                                    Maybe<
                                                                        {
                                                                            __typename?: 'WordpressMenuItemToMenuItemConnectionEdge';
                                                                        } & {
                                                                            node: Maybe<
                                                                                {
                                                                                    __typename?: 'WordpressMenuItem';
                                                                                } & DynamicNavFragmentFragment
                                                                            >;
                                                                        }
                                                                    >
                                                                >
                                                            >;
                                                        }
                                                    >;
                                                } & DynamicNavFragmentFragment
                                            >;
                                        }
                                    >
                                >
                            >;
                        }
                    >;
                }
            >;
        }
    >;
};
```

Code from `pages/index.tsx` where DynamicNavQuery data was initially populated then swiftly overwritten by ServicesTopQuery data

```
import { Container } from '@/components/UI';
import { initializeApollo, addApolloState } from '@/lib/apollo';
import { LandingHero } from '@/components/Landing';
import ServiceTopCoalesced from '@/components/ServicesTop/services-top-coalesced';
import AppLayout from '@/components/Layout/layout';
import {
    GetStaticPropsContext,
    GetStaticPropsResult,
    InferGetStaticPropsType
} from 'next';
import {
    ServicesTopQuery,
    ServicesTopQueryVariables,
    ServicesTopDocument,
    DynamicNavDocument,
    DynamicNavQueryVariables,
    DynamicNavQuery
} from '@/graphql/generated/graphql';

export function Index({
    other,
    popular,
    Header,
    Footer
}: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) {
    return (
        <>
            <AppLayout
                title={'✂ The Fade Room Inc. ✂'}
                Header={Header}
                Footer={Footer}
                hero={<LandingHero />}
            >
                <Container clean className='fit'>
                    <ServiceTopCoalesced other={other} popular={popular} />
                </Container>
            </AppLayout>
        </>
    );
}

export async function getStaticProps(
    ctx: GetStaticPropsContext
): Promise<
    GetStaticPropsResult<{
        other: ServicesTopQuery['other'];
        popular: ServicesTopQuery['popular'];
        Header: DynamicNavQuery['Header'];
        Footer: DynamicNavQuery['Footer'];
    }>
> {
    const apolloClient = initializeApollo();
    await apolloClient.query<
        DynamicNavQuery,
        DynamicNavQueryVariables
    >({
        query: DynamicNavDocument,
        variables: {
            idHead: 'Header',
            idFoot: 'Footer'
        }
    });

    await apolloClient.query<
        ServicesTopQuery,
        ServicesTopQueryVariables
    >({
        query: ServicesTopDocument,
        variables: {
            other: 'all',
            popular: 'popular-service'
        }
    });
    return addApolloState(apolloClient, {
        props: {},
        revalidate: 10
    });
}
export default Index;
```

The DynamicNavQuery data was populated as intended, then my fallback loading component was rendered following initial DOM render for a quarter second or so, then the DynamicNavQuery data disappeared and ServicesTopQuery data was populated instead. So, the existing cache data was overwritten with incoming data sharing the same top level field `wordpress` and __typename `WordPressRootQuery` in the apollo client cache. To remedy this behavior I consulted the apollo docs and updated the instantiation of the `new InMemoryCache` class with the following:

```
cache: new InMemoryCache({
            typePolicies: {
                Query: {
                    fields: {
                        wordpress: {
                            merge(existing, incoming, { mergeObjects }) {
                                // invoking nested merge functions
                                return mergeObjects(existing, incoming);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

The above prevented existing `wordpress` field data from being overwritten by incoming `wordpress` field data, resolving the issue. The process of migrating from a headless WordPress endpoint to a OneGraph endpoint proved more cumbersome than initially anticipated, so I figured I'd follow-up with a detailed response in case someone runs into a similar problem down the road.